# Работают ли function declaration и function expression в одну строку?

Tags: javascript

Как я вижу, в одну строку работает только стрелочные функции.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const out = document.querySelector('.out');

let f1 = () => out.innerHTML = ('<button>Click!</button>');
input.oninput = f1;
```

```html
<input type="text" value="4">
<div class="out"></div>
```

Это так? Или я ошибаюсь?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function test() { alert(1); };
const test2 = function() { alert(2); };

test();
test2();
```

Хоть весь код можете в одну строку сделать (как почти любые минимайзеры)

---

```js
const input=document.querySelector("input"),out=document.querySelector(".out");let f1=()=>out.innerHTML="<button>Click!</button>";function test(){alert(1)}input.oninput=f1;const test2=function(){alert(2)};test(),test2();
```

```html
<input type="text" value="4">
<div class="out"></div>
```

Comment: Наверное, я не совсем правильно выразилась. Я имела в виду вот что... когда добавляется код в одну строку, ему обычно не пишут фигурные скобки. Все вполне может работать и так. Но поэкспериментировав, я заметила, что без фигурных скобок код работает только в стрелочных функциях. В любых других такой возможности нет почему-то - выдает ошибку сразу же

Comment: @Eva да, в стрелочных функциях отсутсвие фигурных скобок равно вот такому значению `return EXPRESSION`, то есть без них сразу возвращается значение, в других функциях конечно такого нет